# Return R output to Java when using RServe

Tags: java, r, rserve

I am using rServe to integrate R and Java. I'm able to call R function from Java and that function returns summary of variable. But the problem is I am unable to display that summary in Java. Below is the snippet of Java code I'm using.

```
RConnection c = new RConnection();
c.eval("library(ggplot)");
REXP desc = c.eval("describe(mpg)");
System.out.println(desc.asString());
```

describe function in R gives following output.

```
describe(mpg)
mpg 

 11  Variables      234  Observations
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
manufacturer 
       n  missing distinct 
     234        0       15 

audi (18, 0.077), chevrolet (19, 0.081), dodge (37, 0.158), ford (25,
0.107), honda (9, 0.038), hyundai (14, 0.060), jeep (8, 0.034), land
rover (4, 0.017), lincoln (3, 0.013), mercury (4, 0.017), nissan (13,
0.056), pontiac (5, 0.021), subaru (14, 0.060), toyota (34, 0.145)
```

Answer (score 1):

The way that I capture my R output in java is:

```
String ret = c.eval("paste(capture.output(describe(mpg))),collapse='\\n')").asString();
System.out.print(ret);
```